# Responsive Email - Conditional Statements causing problems in Outlook

Tags: email, responsive-design, outlook, html-email

I am building a template for responsive emails and in one section I have two blocks of text which we want to stack in smaller devices. Strangely, the Outlook conditional statements are causing extra padding around them in Outlook only. Thy work great with cells that contain images etc but when cells contain only text it is as if the cell collapses. Once i remove the conditionals the cells sit exactly where I want them to. I am using Litmus to run the tests, not sure if I can post a link to the test results since password is needed. Here is a fiddle to show the code: http://jsfiddle.net/roob/bmeh368w/
conditional statements for outlook:

```
              <first text block>

              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
              </td>
              <td align="left" valign="top" width="300">
              <![endif]-->

              <second block>

              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
              </td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Remove the IE check, it has no effect in Outlook and remove the parenthesis.        <!--[if gte mso 9]>        <![endif]-->

Comment: I have been able to control the width of tables with the conditionals in past emails, in this case it is making a negative difference in Outlook only. Incidentally I forgot to mention the problem here is only Outlook 2013/2010/2007. If you are suggesting removing them then why is every blog suggesting using them to make emails responsive in Outlook? Only asking to further my knowledge etc. Here is a screenshot of litmus test in Outlook 2013, same blocks of text with and w/o conditionals: http://s1228.photobucket.com/user/roobp57/media/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-26%20at%2011.36.01%20AM.png.html

Comment: removing parenthesis made no difference - just ran more tests and got same results. For reference I based my template partly on Fabio Carneiros techniques and part from sources such as Campaign Monitor etc: https://litmus.com/community/code/361-responsive-for-gmail-app-that-works-with-everything-else-too

Comment: sorry David I didnt realize what u were saying. The IE check is there for outlook 2003 and earlier which use IE as rendering machine.

Comment: If you'd like to take a look at [my template](https://github.com/dcondrey/html-email/tree/master/template), it works well across all clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I see the issue. The coditional code has align="center" in the table instead of align="left" and the two TDs at 300px when  the table is only supposed to be 270px or 280px.  This is adding an extra 30px and 20px of 'whitespace' around the tables. Change the size of the tds and table width and it should match as you want.

```html
            <table width="100%" class="emailContainer" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000000">   
              <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:25px 20px 10px 20px;">
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                  <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="520">
                  <tr>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" width="260">
                  <![endif]-->
                    <table class="flexibleColumn" width="260" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 10px 0 0;">
                          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;color:#b8b8b8;font-size:13px;text-align:left;padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" valign="top">
                              <b>SPOTLIGHT</b></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td valign="top" style="font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;line-height:19px;text-align:left;padding:0 20px 0 0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
                              <a href="http://graphics.latimes.com/travel-to-cuba/#navtype=outfit" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none; font-size:13px; font-weight:bold;">Visiting a long-forbidden neighbor</a> | Only 93 miles from the U.S., Cuba has been closed to most American tourists for more than 50 years. But no more. Soon Americans will be flocking to this island nation. Before this happens, get an exclusive look inside the country's mysterious appeal.<br />
                              <a href="http://graphics.latimes.com/travel-to-cuba/#navtype=outfit" target="_blank" style="color:#bc3133;text-decoration:none;font-size:11px; font-style:italic;">Read more &raquo;</a></td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                  </td>
                  <td align="left" valign="top" width="260">
                  <![endif]-->
                    <table width="260" class="flexibleColumn" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0;">
                          <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;color:#b8b8b8;font-size:13px;text-align:left;padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;" valign="top">RELATED</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td style="font-family:Georgia, Times, serif;color:#ffffff;font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;line-height:19px;text-align:left;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;" valign="top">
                            <a href="http://www.latimes.com/travel/la-tr-d-cuba-need-to-know-20150510-story.html" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">What to know before you go &raquo;</a><br />
                            <a href="http://graphics.latimes.com/cuba-cars/" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">Getting a handle on its classic cars &raquo;</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.latimes.com/travel/la-tr-d-cuba-watson-hemingway-20150510-story.html" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">Ernest Hemingway's homestead &raquo;</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.latimes.com/travel/la-tr-cuba-then-now-20150506-htmlstory.html" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;">Photo gallery: Then and now &raquo;</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.latimes.com/la-tr-cuba-video-playlist-20150507-premiumvideoplaylist.html" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">Video on navigating the country &raquo;</a><br />
                            <a href="http://www.latimes.com/travel/la-tr-readers-photos-of-cuba-20150414-pg-photogallery.html" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;">Readers share their photos &raquo;</a></td>
                          </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                  <![endif]-->
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>   
          <!-- Stacking blocks -->
```

Comment: You are in fact correct but problem still persists. The tables should be 260px, and I had already tried that before posting here - I just re-tried it - and still get same results. I just updated the fiddle with the correct widths.

Comment: so the plot thickens: today running litmus tests shows that the conditional statements are placing extra padding elsewhere too. Up until today it was only doing that with text-only cells.

Comment: i think I have it.  had to change the conditional table to align="left" instead of center.  That combined with reducing the table and td sizes seems to have done the trick from my tests. Edited in my answer

Comment: That actually did it, I'm surprised I didnt catch that. Thank you, the table alignment also solved the other puzzle that I mentioned was happening elsewhere in the email above.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup of message bodies. You can find supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties described in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)

Hope you will find this information helpful.

Comment: thank you Eugene but not what I'm looking for. I've already coded quite a few responsive emails and familiar with the concept, just have not come across this anomaly and wondering if I was missing something